# How to iterate over a Response Object

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm making a `fetch` call to an API using a little fetch wrapper that returns a `Promise.reject` if there's an error.

```
function fetchErrorHandler(url, options) {
    if (options == null) options = {};
    if (options.credentials == null) options.credentials = 'same-origin';
    return fetch(url, options).then( response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            return Promise.reject(response);
        }
        return response;
    })
}
fetch('/cool/api/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(body => { //...})
    .catch(error => {
        // Let's do something smart.
    });
```

What I'd like to do is iterate over the `Response` object and save the key: value pairs. So some inside that catch block:

```
for (let item in error) {
    if (error.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        log(error[item] + ': ' + item);    
     }
 }
```

...but that produces no results.

There are two possibilities I can think of here. The `error` is actually another Promise, in which case I need to do something else. Or, the `Response` object doesn't have it's `OwnProperty`'s. Either way I'm not sure how to get the data I want. Any clues?

Btw, I've also try `Object.keys(error)` and the same thing occured

Comment: Yes, a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) doesn't have any own enumerable properties (most likely all the usual ones are inherited getters). What exactly do you expect to iterate? The HTTP body?

Comment: Notice that `error` is not always a response. It could as well be a network error, when `fetch()` doesn't even reach the server.

Comment: Both good points. If it is a not-ok response I guess I can use the static properties listed in the above linked doc. If it's a network error... I guess I can handle that differently.

Comment: If it is a non-ok response, you can still access the headers or wait to read the body with the `.text()` or `.json()` methods (or whatever it is).